# How to create Html Table from viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I am in the process to create a datable where each cell in the html  table could be a input control, or another html control like select (for now I need to make things work for input controls). Something like this:

```html
<Table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>                
             <td><input type="text" value=80 /></td>
             <td><input type="text" value=100 /></td>
         </tr>         
        <tr>                
             <td><input type="text" value=120 /></td>
             <td><input type="text" value=140 /></td>
         </tr>  
        <tr>                
             <td><input type="text" value=160 /></td>
             <td><input type="text" value=180 /></td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

What I have found for the moment is just the creation of data tables using simple databinding so each cell it's a readonly cell.

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/Fyat8/) you can see what I expect get in some way.

UPDATE: What I need it's the creation of a table where the number of columns and the number of rows will depend of the datasource (in this case properties from the viewmodel).

Comment: You're not very clear: what is your exact question/problem? Where did you get stuck / why didn't your solutions work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the fiddle that you are referencing is that the properties on the items in the list are not observable. I use the knockout mapping plugin to do this for me.

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRYV5/3/) which demonstrates values changing in the lower table when you edit values in the upper table.

And here is the code, but remember to reference the knockout mapping plugin.

****UPDATED ANSWER....SEE COMMENTS, AND [UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vRYV5/3/)****

HTML

```
Generated table using ko    
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind='foreach: datacolumns'>
            <th>
                <span data-bind="text: ColumnName"></span>
            </th>      
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataModel">
        <tr  data-bind='foreach: $root.datacolumns'>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value:$parent['Value' + ColumnName]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
And this table updates when you tab out of the textboxes
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind='foreach: datacolumns'>
            <th>
                <span data-bind="text: ColumnName"></span>
            </th>      
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataModel">
        <tr  data-bind='foreach: $root.datacolumns'>
            <td data-bind="text:$parent['Value' + ColumnName]"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
function ViewModel(model,columns) {
    var self = this;          

    self.dataModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);  
    self.datacolumns = columns;    
}    
var columns =  [{ColumnName:'Column1'},{ColumnName:'Column2'}];

var model =  [
    { ValueColumn1: '80', ValueColumn2: '100' },
    { ValueColumn1: '120', ValueColumn2: '140' },
    { ValueColumn1: '160', ValueColumn2: '180' }
] ;

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(model,columns));
```

Comment: thank you for the edition and the quick answer. Maybe I did some mistake trying describe my problem :(. 
My issue/question is related with how to create a dinamic html table (with input or antoher control) using as datasource properties from a viewmodel. In my example i puted two tables:
1) To show what i want to show.
2) A simple example about how to create a table from the viewmodel.
i.e getting the columns and number of rows from the database and create a dynamic table. Again, thank you for your reply.

Comment: I have updated the script. you can see my changes here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/vRYV5/1/